# cannot find EJB reference while deploying ADF Fusion Webapp into oracle weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0, jdeveloper, oracle-adf, data-controls

I created a Fusion Webapplication project with Oracle jdeveloper 11g (11.1.5 but the same problem occours with the 11.2.1 version). Then I created a jsf page and I deployed the project to an external weblogic server (WL 10.3) with the ADF runtime support and evrithing where working.

Then I created the POJOs object (to the model project, because I have 2 proj: Model and ViewController for the web pages and backing beans) from the DB tables and a session bean who provides queries methods. After that (and so far everything it's ok) I added an ADF Data Control bound to the session bean and then I bound (via editor) one of these methods into the jsf page using an ADF table.

If I run the project using the run button everything work, but if I deploy it into both the external deployment WL server and in the internal one I get the following error

```
[05:30:04 PM] [Deployer:149193]Operation 'deploy' on application 'Prova_application1' has failed on 'AdminServer'
[05:30:04 PM] [Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]deploy application Prova_application1 on AdminServer.: Could not setup environment.
[05:30:04 PM] Weblogic Server Exception: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Could not setup environment
[05:30:04 PM] Caused by: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160167]The module Prova-ViewController-context-root in application Prova_application1 uses ejb-links but no EJB modules were found for this application.
[05:30:04 PM]   See server logs or server console for more details.
[05:30:04 PM] weblogic.application.ModuleException: Could not setup environment
[05:30:04 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
[05:30:04 PM] Remote deployment failed
```

but there is such refernce into the web.xml and I bound the Model project into the deployment descriptor. I red every post in the web but I still can't face the problem.

The web.xml in the ViewController project contains the EJB reference (automatically created from jdeveloper) and I bound everithing the Model project but it still doesn't work.

Comment: looks like only ViewController web app is getting deployed without the Model session beans

Comment: I solved by adding to the model an ejb deployment profile (by default the adf profile is used) and referencing it to from the view. Infact otherwhise the model project is not seen like an ejb module so that any ejb reference can be solved within the project. Thanks anyway, bye.

Answer (score 0):

In JDeveloper IDE 
you need to set ejb-jar.xml path.
- Right click on your project
- Choose Project Properties
- Go to EJB Module
- Set EJB Version (For example: "2.1")
- Set ejb-jar.xml path (For example: "..\src\META-INF\ejb-jar.xml")

I hope it works..